# react-adsense causing many errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adsense

I'm trying to use AdSense in my react app, but am having trouble figuring it out. I read the docs on npm react-adsense, but still am confused. Where exactly do I put the ad? As of now I have it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import AdSense from "react-adsense";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <AdSense.Google
        client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        slot="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        style={{ display: "block" }}
        format="auto"
        responsive="true"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then I render it in my main application.

I get a bunch of errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.
```

I know that adsense wants me to put this script tag somewhere `<script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>` but I'm not sure where it's supposed to go. As of now I put it here in my index file:

```
  <body>
    <script
      async
   src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-2806029732302260"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </body>
```

My page breaks when I put this in. I assume it's the placement of these script tags but I couldn't find any documentation on applying these ads to react apps.

EDIT:
Sometimes, the page doesn't break, but the ad still doesn't show up. Just a blank div where it's supposed to be, although that might be from not understanding how to render adsense in general. This is what's rendered:

```
<div>
  <ins
    class="adsbygoogle"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-WHATEVER
    data-ad-slot="WHATEVER"
    data-ad-layout=""
    data-ad-layout-key=""
    data-ad-format="auto"
    data-full-width-responsive="true"
    style="display: block; height: 280px"
    data-adsbygoogle-status="done"
    data-ad-status="unfilled"
    ><div
      id="aswift_1_host"
      tabindex="0"
      title="Advertisement"
      aria-label="Advertisement"
      style="
        border: none;
        height: 280px;
        width: 436px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        visibility: visible;
        background-color: transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: visible;
      "
    >
      <iframe
        id="aswift_1"
        name="aswift_1"
        style="
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          border: 0;
          width: 436px;
          height: 280px;
        "
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"
        width="436"
        height="280"
        frameborder="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        marginheight="0"
        vspace="0"
        hspace="0"
        allowtransparency="true"
        scrolling="no"
        allow="attribution-reporting"
        src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=WHATEVER
        data-google-container-id="a!2"
        data-load-complete="true"
      ></iframe></div
  ></ins>
</div>
```

But this only happens once in a few refreshes, the rest of the time the page breaks with the same error:

```
TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Have your tried to load the `adsbygoogle` script in the head of your index file? I Always do it like this and it works for me.

Comment: yeah still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't need to install NPM package Just use this code**

Place Script code in head tag

```
<head>
<script async 
 src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca- 
  pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
```

Make a AdsComponent file

```
import React, { useEffect  } from 'react';

const AdsComponent = (props) => {
  const { dataAdSlot } = props;  



useEffect(() => {

    try {
        (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    }

    catch (e) {

    }

},[]);



return (
    <>
        <ins className="adsbygoogle"
            style={{ display: "block" }}
            data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            data-ad-slot={dataAdSlot}
            data-ad-format="auto"
            data-full-width-responsive="true">
        </ins>
    </>
);
 };

  export default AdsComponent;
```

**And Now Finally time to show our ads in our React Pages Like this.**

```
import './App.css';
 import AdsComponent from './AdsComponent';

  function App() {

 //Note provide dataAdSlot value of your data-ad-slot which is your ad unit no.
    return (
    <>
        <h1>Place To show Google AdSense</h1>
       <AdsComponent dataAdSlot='X7XXXXXX5X' />
    </>

    );
  }

  export default App;
```

Comment: same error `TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them`